# Customizing "lightning:availableForFlowActions" for Aura Action in flow

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow, aura-attribute, custom-actions

In principle, I want to be able to customize the information displayed to an admin when they access and insert a custom action for a flow. For example, I'd like to have a limited picklist for the user to select from or provide help text to guide the admin so they can use the action most effectively. I've read most of the documentation on https://developer.salesforce.com and have not been able to find anything specifically related to this problem.

What I've Tried:

1. modified aura attribute component to include type:Set/List; but get "The lightning:availableForFlowActions interface doesn't support these attribute types in the design resource: list."
2. modified design attribute to include a datasource; but no change

Where should I go next? It seems very little customization of the "lightning:availableForFlowActions" is possible.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). Be sure to take the [Tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour) & look in the [Help Center](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help). I can't answer this, but have you checked on [UnofficialSF](https://unofficialsf.com) to see if they have anything that might help with this?

Comment: It sounds like there are two asks here -- add help text to the component customization panel, and use a picklist in that panel. The help text should be a simple task of adding a description="..." attribute to the design:attribute tag (in the design file). Let us know if that doesn't work.

In terms of getting a picklist to show properly, I have used datasource to successfully render a picklist, although there are some limitations. Can you post the code that you're trying to use?

Comment: Nope, description does nothing on the "New Action" screen as you insert the action onto the flow. The field still says "Enter a value" on hover and "enter value or search resource". The picklist isn't a global value or a datasource value. It is a static resource I want only in the flow. Even to just limit the types of variables that can be passed into the Action flow screen would help.